# HSP and HFP profiles for hands-free telephony

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluez, pulseaudio, qualcomm

I am attempting to implement hands-free telephony on my board, I successfully connected my android phone to the board via bluetooth module in phone and media audio sharing mode.
The chip i use is Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174. I have pulseaudio 11.1, bluetoothctl: 5.49, and ofono 1.22 setup on my board.
I was able to play media files via bluetooth by this. But when a call connected the bluetooth speaker works properly, i.e. I can hear what is said on the other end of call via my headphone, but what I say is not heard at the other end( I guess there is some error in getting the data from mic or in transmitting data from bluetooth device). I get the following log message keeps appearing many times as soon as a call is initiated

```
"***Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0***

***Bluetooth: hci0 sending frame failed (-27)***

***Bluetooth: hci0 sending frame failed (-27)***"
```

The microphone on the phone is also not functioning(after bluetooth connection is established).
Also in `*hciconfig -a*`  it is found as follows

```
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:0E:8E:76:00:55  ACL MTU: 1024:8  SCO MTU: 50:8
    UP RUNNING PSCAN 
    RX bytes:810924 acl:982 sco:18885 events:670 errors:0
    **TX bytes:528349 acl:530 sco:10271 commands:108 errors:111**
    Features: 0xff 0xfe 0x8f 0xfe 0xd8 0x3f 0x5b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: mydevice
    Class: 0x2c041c
    Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Audio
    Device Class: Audio/Video, Portable Audio
    HCI Version: 4.2 (0x8)  Revision: 0x0
    LMP Version: 4.2 (0x8)  Subversion: 0x25a
    Manufacturer: Qualcomm
```

The steps I followed to setup connection are as follows

```
    $ hciconfig hci0 up
    $ pactl list sources short
    $ pactl list sinks short
    $ bluetoothctl
    agent on
    scan on
    scan off
    pair <address>
    connect<address>
```

My hcitool connections gives the following

```
    $ hcitool con
    Connections:
    < ACL 78:C3:E9:21:1B:0B handle 2 state 1 lm MASTER AUTH ENCRYPT
```

No SCO connection is shown here.
How can I solve this and implement proper hands-free telephony?

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact error. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).